# How do I wait for a response from a serial port command before executing the new command?

Tags: c#, .net, serial-port, at-command, teraterm

I'm trying to execute some AT commands one at a time.
In Teraterm I execute this:

```shell
sendln "AT+AS=0"
waitln "OK"
sendln "AT+CREG=?"
sendln "AT+creg=0,1"
pause 15
sendln "AT+creg=?"
```

How would I execute these commands in a C# desktop application targeting .NET Framework 4.8?
My current code looks like this:

```c#
serialPort.Write("AT+AS=0");
await Task.Delay(1000);
while(!serialPort.ReadLine().Contains("OK")) ;
serialPort.Write("AT+CREG=?");
await Task.Delay(1000);
serialPort.Write("AT+CREG=0,1");
await Task.Delay(15000);
serialPort.Write("AT+CREG=?");
```

Comment: What kind of application?  Please tag with [tag:.net] or [tag:.net-core], as appropriate.  Does the current function work or not?  What you have might work unmodified, or perhaps substituting `Thread.Sleep()` for `Task.Delay()` if `async`/`await` support isn't available for some reason.

Comment: I use .Net 4.8 . My function works processes the commands but I'm not sure if it actually executes these commands... How can I make sure serialport actually writes these commands to target device?

Comment: For a request-response dialogue with a device such as a modem, the simplest & most efficient implementation uses blocking I/O.  Inserting delays/waits in your code is sub-optimal.  Let the OS schedule your program/process using its built-in I/O events, rather than try to supplement the OS by adding delays & try to poll for data by your program

Comment: Side comment: in order to check registration status you need to issue `AT+CREG?` command (without '='). `AT+CREG=?` is the test command and just provides you the parameters ranges of +CREG command.

Answer (score 0):

Change `await Task.Delay(1000);` to Task.Delay(1000).Wait(); or `Thread.Sleep(1000)`

`Wait` and `await` - are similar conceptually, but completely different in functionality.